# How to transfrom CollisionPolygon2D according to the Vertex Shader applied to a Sprite?

Tags: collision-detection, godot, vertex-shader

Consider this:

```
* KinematicBody2D
- * Sprite
- * CollisionPolygon2D
```

And a vertex shader:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

void vertex() {
    VERTEX.y += sin(2.0 * TIME) * 10.0;
}
```

When the vertex shader is added to the `CanvasItem.material` of the Sprite and the CollisionPolygon2D they both move at the same time:

[image]

But if one modifies the shader like that:

```
void vertex() {
  VERTEX.y += sin(UV.y * 2.0 * TIME) * 10.0;
}
```

It produces that:

[image]

How to transfrom CollisionPolygon2D according to the Vertex Shader applied to the Sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this, for reasons I'll mention below. However, to answer the question…

The reason why you don't see the `CollisionPolygon2D` move the same way is because it does not have `UV` coordinates set (because it does not need to be textured).

We write the `UV` coordinates ourselves:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform vec2 size;

void vertex() {
    UV = (VERTEX + (size * 0.5)) / size;
    VERTEX.y += sin(UV.y * 2.0 * TIME) * 10.0;
}
```

The uniform `size` should be set to the size of the sprite you want to match.

However, **this is not useful**, what we are getting from the shader is purely graphical. The physics server is unaware of it, and will not use it. Thus the motion generated from the shader will not cause collisions.

Most of the time not changing the `CollisionPolygon2D` is correct. That would make the animation purely visual. If purely visual is OK for you, then simply don't do this.

---

Alright, if we need to animate the `CollisionPolygon2D` in a way that works well with physics, how would we go about it?

As it turns out, if were to move or scale the `CollisionPolygon2D` without moving the `KinematicBody2D` collision may not register.

That also means that it is not useful to animate the `CollisionPolygon2D` using `AnimationPlayer`.

Speaking of `AnimationPlayer`, using it to animate the `KinematicBody2D` would work, but it is not ideal, because the animation would be absolute, and presumably we want to move `KinematicBody2D` from code.

Thus, we are going to solve this with GDScript.

---

Since we want the top of the `CollisionPolygon2D` and the `Sprite` to not move. Position them from the origin downwards (That is, do not have them centered to the `KinematicBody2D`). That will make the code much simpler.

I'll give you an initial version:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _physics_process(_delta):
    # other motion

    var time = OS.get_ticks_msec() / 1000.0
    scale.y = 1.0 + sin(2.0 * time) * 10.0 / ($Sprite.scale.y * $Sprite.texture.get_height())
```

Note that assuming that the `$Sprite.scale.y * $Sprite.texture.get_height()` we could replace it with a constant. For example, the default Godot icon.png is 64x64, assuming it is not scaled, we have `10.0 / (1.0 * 64.0)` which is `0.15625`.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _physics_process(_delta):
    # other motion

    var time = OS.get_ticks_msec() / 1000.0
    scale.y = 1.0 + sin(2.0 * time) * 0.15625
```

Something else, let us assume that we have some other motion that also changes the scale. To handle that you can keep track of how this motion affected the scale in a separate variable. For example:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var old_scale:float = 1.0

func _physics_process(_delta):
    # other motion, for example scale.y += 0.001

    var time = OS.get_ticks_msec() / 1000.0
    var new_scale = 1.0 + sin(2.0 * time) * 0.15625
    scale.y += new_scale - old_scale
    old_scale = new_scale
```

Finally, if you want to see this motion on the editor, you could turn this into a `tool` script. You may have to close and open the scene again to take effect. However, if you do that, it will keep the scale it had at the moment you start the game. Thus, I suggest to reset the sacle on `_ready`. See [Running code in the editor](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/running_code_in_the_editor.html).